# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 & 14.04 wifi issues

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros

I have a Lenovo B50-30 Touch laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

The laptop has a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01).

I am having wifi issues.  I can barely connect to the Comcast router in my room.  It's 10 feet away from my laptop and I have 2 bars.

```
alan@Lenovo:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan wlan0
 Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 98:6B:3D:19:05:C0
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=31/70  Signal level=-79 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Rose"
```

I am frequently disconnected from the access point.

My cell phone (Galaxy S4) is connected with a single strength of -36dBm

If I go to a coffee shop, I'm unable to connect to the public wifi network because the signal is so low.